On nontrapping manifolds
Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a compact connected smooth Riemannian manifold without boundary.
Let $U \subset M$ be a smooth submanifold of codimension zero with smooth boundary and assume that $U$ is nontrapping, meaning that all inextendible unit speed geodesics eventually exit the set $U$. Does there exist a point $p \in M\setminus U$ such that $A(p) \subset M\setminus U$?
Here, $A(p)$ is the antipodal set of $p$ defined by
$$ A(p)=\{ q\in M\,:\, \textrm{dist}_g(q,p)\geq \textrm{dist}_g(y,p) \quad \forall\, y\in M\}.$$

If I understood the question correctly, the manifold $M=\mathbb{S}^1$ with the geodesic metric, and the set $U$ equals $\mathbb{S}^1$ minus a small open interval, is a counterexample (I posted it as a comment in case the OP wanted to modify the question)

@SaúlRM oh dang, that's much easier than the one I posted.

Start with the line segment
$$ \{(x,y) : x\in [1,1000000], y = \epsilon x\} $$
for some tiny $\epsilon$. Form the surface by rotating the segment about the $x$ axis. This makes a section of a very pointy cone. Cap it off smoothly on both ends to make it convex, while keeping it still a surface of revolution. Call this your $M$.
Take your $U$ to be all of the cone section plus the cap on the small end. As a surface of revolution it is easy to check that $U$ is non-trapping. But every point on the large cap, by virtue of the cone being very long and pointy, has its antipodal set entirely contained in $U$.
So the answer to your question is "not always".
